# SQL query for multiple rows in single column

Tags: sql, database

I want to design table for **patient prescription** it contains pat_id, date and more than one  prescription prescribed by doctor

How to do this?

Give me a sample query to create table

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on what and how questions should be asked.

Comment: you should have 2 tables: `patient` and `prescription`. having multiple (but not constant) number of prescriptions for patient in one row is violation of 1st normal form (and you cannot even implement this in relational model)

Comment: This not sufficient information. If more than two or two prescription then you should define separate prescription table

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a good quetion and is a very likely candidate for someone down voting it.
Look here for an example schema

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/patient_care/index.htm
[image: schema]

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Patient
(
      PacientID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , FirstName VARCHAR(30)
    , LastName VARCHAR(30)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.PatientPrescription
(
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , PacientID INT
    , DoctorID INT
    , [Descritpion] VARCHAR(500)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Doctor
(
      DoctorID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , FirstName VARCHAR(30)
    , LastName VARCHAR(30)
)
GO
```